# How do I remove associated rows in Excel when cell contains specific text and there are duplicates in a different row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking at a spreadsheet where in one column there are order numbers and in another column there are products. In the order column one order will be broken down into 2 or more rows depending how many products were on that order. I need to be able to remove all rows that contain a specific product along with the rows that contain the same order number. I could do this manually but wondering if there is a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some helper columns. Here's a method where Column D is looking up the Product ID to see if it's one to exclude. The product id to exclude is found in cell H1.

Cell D2 formula:

```
=C2=$H$1
```

Drag it down.

The next part can be done with formulas, but I'm using another method by creating a pivot table on data in columns A through D. Rows is your Order ID, and filter is Flagged_Product (set to TRUE).

Then column E could look up to see if that order has any products that are flagged.

Cell E2 formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G:G,B2) > 0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Drag it down. Sort by column E and remove the TRUE values.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!